# Bellman-Ford: Find all nodes that have minus infinite distance to source

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

Given a weighted, directed graph (V, E) may contains some negative cycles and a source node `s`, I would like to know for all node `u`, if there is a path from `s` to `u` but there is no shortest path from `s` to `u` (the distance from `s` to `u` is minus infinite). To do this I implemented a version of the Bellman-Ford algorithm:

```
Do V iterations of Bellman-Ford, save all nodes relaxed on Vth iteration to a queue `Q`
Do BFS with `Q` and find all nodes reachable from `Q`
All those nodes and only those can have infinite distance from `s`
```

Here is BFS:

```
visited(Q.first) = true
while Q not empty:
    u <- Q.deQueue()
    shortest[u] = 0 // there is no shortest path from `s` to `u`
    for all (u, v) in E:
        if not visited(v):
            visited(v) = true
            Q.push(v)
```

This algorithm is the best I can come up with and sadly it fails some test cases. I would be greatly appreciated if you guys can help, thanks.

Comment: When you say "is infinite," just to clarify, you mean "is minus infinity," yes? Otherwise, how are you modelling "a path exists but its sum-of-weights is infinite", what sort of situation provokes that?

Comment: Yeah, what I meant is "minus infinity" since there are negative cycles in the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a morning of testing, I just figured out that my solution is RIGHT, the problem I had before is because of overflow (I use `10^19` to declare `infinity` for all vertices at the beginning and it can leads to overflow for some test cases).